# Pymongo-spark: BsonSerializationException about decoding a BSON string

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark, pymongo, bson

I'm running some PySpark code through an IPython notebook that loads and processes three Mongo collections as RDDs, then merges them (with unionAll and dropDuplicates), converts the merged RDD to a DataFrame and writes the result to a CSV.

The Spark job is failing, apparently because Pymongo-spark is unable to load just a few documents. **How would I ignore any bad documents, or add a try/except block to ignore this exception, and what does the exception mean?** Loading RDDs with `sc.mongoRDD(database_uri)` doesn't allow me to insert any error handling logic.

I ran into this exception on a few tasks:

```
org.bson.BsonSerializationException: While decoding a BSON string found a size that is not a positive number: 0
at org.bson.io.ByteBufferBsonInput.readString(ByteBufferBsonInput.java:107)
at org.bson.BsonBinaryReader.doReadString(BsonBinaryReader.java:223)
at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.readString(AbstractBsonReader.java:430)
at org.bson.codecs.StringCodec.decode(StringCodec.java:39)
at org.bson.codecs.StringCodec.decode(StringCodec.java:28)
at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.readValue(DBObjectCodec.java:306)
at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.readDocument(DBObjectCodec.java:345)
at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.readValue(DBObjectCodec.java:286)
at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.readArray(DBObjectCodec.java:333)
at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.readValue(DBObjectCodec.java:289)
at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.readDocument(DBObjectCodec.java:345)
at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.readValue(DBObjectCodec.java:286)
at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.readDocument(DBObjectCodec.java:345)
at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.decode(DBObjectCodec.java:136)
at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.decode(DBObjectCodec.java:61)
at com.mongodb.CompoundDBObjectCodec.decode(CompoundDBObjectCodec.java:43)
at com.mongodb.CompoundDBObjectCodec.decode(CompoundDBObjectCodec.java:27)
at com.mongodb.connection.ReplyMessage.<init>(ReplyMessage.java:57)
at com.mongodb.connection.QueryProtocol.execute(QueryProtocol.java:305)
at com.mongodb.connection.QueryProtocol.execute(QueryProtocol.java:54)
at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor.execute(DefaultServer.java:159)
at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.executeProtocol(DefaultServerConnection.java:286)
at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.query(DefaultServerConnection.java:209)
at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation$1.call(FindOperation.java:493)
at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation$1.call(FindOperation.java:480)
at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:239)
at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:212)
at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:480)
at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:77)
at com.mongodb.Mongo.execute(Mongo.java:772)
at com.mongodb.Mongo$2.execute(Mongo.java:759)
at com.mongodb.DBCursor.initializeCursor(DBCursor.java:851)
at com.mongodb.DBCursor.hasNext(DBCursor.java:152)
at com.mongodb.hadoop.input.MongoRecordReader.nextKeyValue(MongoRecordReader.java:78)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(NewHadoopRDD.scala:143)
at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:39)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.hasNext(SerDeUtil.scala:116)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.foreach(SerDeUtil.scala:111)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:420)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3.apply(PythonRDD.scala:249)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1699)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scala:208)
```

For reference, I'm running Spark 1.5.1 on four workers with the following submit arguments:

```
export PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS="--master spark://<IP_ADDRESS>:7077 --executor-memory 18g --driver-memory 4g --num-executors 4 --executor-cores 6 --conf spark.cores.max=24 --conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=4g --conf spark.eventLog.enabled=true --conf spark.eventLog.dir=/home/tao/eventLogging --jars /usr/local/spark/lib/mongo-hadoop-spark-1.5.0.jar --driver-class-path /usr/local/spark/lib/mongo-hadoop-spark-1.5.0.jar --packages com.stratio.datasource:spark-mongodb_2.10:0.11.0 --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.4.0 pyspark-shell"
```

I launched an IPython notebook with `ipython notebook --profile=pyspark` to run the following code (simplified):

```
hdfs_path = 'hdfs://<IP address>/path/to/training_data_folder'

rdd1 = sc.mongoRDD(database_uri1)\
         .map(select_certain_fields1)\
         .filter(lambda doc: len(doc.keys()))\
         .map(add_a_field)\
         .map(doc_to_tuple)\
         .filter(len)

rdd2 = sc.mongoRDD(database_uri2)\
         .map(select_certain_fields2)\
         .filter(lambda doc: len(doc.keys()))\
         .map(add_a_field)\
         .map(doc_to_tuple)\
         .filter(len)

rdd3 = sc.mongoRDD(database_uri3)\
         .map(select_certain_fields3)\
         .filter(lambda doc: len(doc.keys()))\
         .map(add_a_field)\
         .map(doc_to_tuple)\
         .filter(len)

df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd1, schema)
df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd2, schema)
df3 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd3, schema)

df_all = df2.unionAll(df3).unionAll(df1)\
                   .dropDuplicates(['caseId', 'timestamp'])

df_all.write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv') \
    .save(hdfs_path + '/all_notes_1.csv')
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what is your question? See how to ask a question at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry about that! I tried to clarify my question.

Comment: You should consider [creating a JIRA issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/HADOOP/). It is rather unlikely will be able to provide a solution here and the exception looks strange. You can also try [Stratio data source](https://github.com/Stratio/Spark-MongoDB) which was much more stable the last time I checked.